# libsdl2-dev : Depends: libsdl2-2.0-0

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies

I'm relatively new to ubuntu and I'm having issues with installing retroarch,and well anything that needs libsdl2-2.0-0 installed, I have tried multiple methods of installation but none seem to work here is the main log for some of the most common methods that have been suggested.

```
sudo apt install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libsdl2-dev : Depends: libsdl2-2.0-0 (= 2.0.4+dfsg1-2ubuntu2) but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
user@user-MS-1492:~$ sudo apt-get update
Get:1 https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease [4,487 B]
Ign:1 https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease
Ign:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease              
Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease    
Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/vlijm/lswitcher/ubuntu xenial InRelease         
Hit:6 http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian xenial InRelease        
Hit:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/brackets/ubuntu xenial InRelease    
Hit:8 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                     
Hit:9 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:10 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
Hit:11 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease
Fetched 4,487 B in 6s (732 B/s)                    
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 1F3045A5DF7587C3
W: The repository 'https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease' is not signed.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
user@user-MS-1492:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libsdl2-dev : Depends: libsdl2-2.0-0 (= 2.0.4+dfsg1-2ubuntu2) but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
user@user-MS-1492:~$ sudo apt -f upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libgsoap8 libqt4-opengl libqt5x11extras5 libsdl-ttf2.0-0 libvncserver1
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libsdl2-2.0-0
The following packages will be upgraded:
  git git-man
2 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 4,146 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,165 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 git-man all 1:2.7.4-0ubuntu1.1 [735 kB]
Get:2 http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 libsdl2-2.0-0 amd64 2.0.4+dfsg1-2ubuntu2 [343 kB]
Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 git amd64 1:2.7.4-0ubuntu1.1 [3,068 kB]
Fetched 4,146 kB in 6s (631 kB/s)                                              
(Reading database ... 253351 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libsdl2-2.0-0_2.0.4+dfsg1-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libsdl2-2.0-0:amd64 (2.0.4+dfsg1-2ubuntu2) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libsdl2-2.0-0_2.0.4+dfsg1-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite shared '/usr/share/doc/libsdl2-2.0-0/copyright', which is different from other instances of package libsdl2-2.0-0:amd64
Preparing to unpack .../git-man_1%3a2.7.4-0ubuntu1.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking git-man (1:2.7.4-0ubuntu1.1) over (1:2.7.4-0ubuntu1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../git_1%3a2.7.4-0ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking git (1:2.7.4-0ubuntu1.1) over (1:2.7.4-0ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu7) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libsdl2-2.0-0_2.0.4+dfsg1-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
user@user-MS-1492:~$ sudo apt -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libgsoap8 libqt4-opengl libqt5x11extras5 libsdl-ttf2.0-0 libvncserver1
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libsdl2-2.0-0
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libsdl2-2.0-0
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/343 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,153 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 253351 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libsdl2-2.0-0_2.0.4+dfsg1-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libsdl2-2.0-0:amd64 (2.0.4+dfsg1-2ubuntu2) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libsdl2-2.0-0_2.0.4+dfsg1-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite shared '/usr/share/doc/libsdl2-2.0-0/copyright', which is different from other instances of package libsdl2-2.0-0:amd64
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu7) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libsdl2-2.0-0_2.0.4+dfsg1-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I really dont know what to do at this stage, if anybody can help I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Fix broken : `sudo apt-get -f install` ... Install libsdl2-dev : `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt install libsdl2-dev`

Comment: Unfortunately these methods did not work fro me, but hopefully it will for someone else thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by rebooting the system entering recovery mode and selecting fix broken packages. Worked like a charm now everything installed just fine.